# display image as image with aspx url

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms

I have an image
( Link: `http://arsenal.ir/images/news/big/b04726ba-84ca-4fc6-bc17-45ba859a54fc.jpg` )

i do not want use this link . i want to have a page

```
 "showimg.aspx"
```

and use this link to show my image

`http://arsenal.ir/showimg.aspx`

and i want to use it like this

```
<img src="http://arsenal.ir/showimg.aspx" alt="text"  />
```

and this tag  show the image ...

AND .... i want to set Width by Query String

(i am using web forms C# )

Comment: gooooooooooners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an empty page with a Response.Write, you can work out your idea from this

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ApriAllegato.aspx.vb" Inherits="LosiFramework.ApriAllegato" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the behind code

```
public partial class ApriAllegato : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string pathCompleto = Request.QueryString["pathCompleto"];
        string filename = ''; //Get the file name from the path
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        if (pathCompleto.EndsWith(".pdf")) {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf; name=" + filename;
        } else {
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream; name=" + filename;
        }
        Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        Response.WriteFile(pathCompleto);
        Response.End();

    }

}
```

Comment: how about width ?!
i want to set width from QueryString

Comment: And ... this show me Blank page

Comment: Did you copy and paste? Read the code and learn, then write your own implementation.